# How to get the industry lost rate in a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

I want to summarize a dataframe with lost rate on industry level using pandas groupby()

my data table looks like below:
**type** contains different industry and **good_bad**=0 means it's bad loan and good_bad=1 means good loan

```
type    | good_bad
food    |    0
food    |    0
food    |    1
Retail  |    1
Retail  |    1
Retail  |    1
Retail  |    0
```

I want to create a new column **lost_rate**, it calculates the lost rate based on occurrence of bad loans for each industry and divide by the total industry count:

```
type    | good_bad  | lost_rate   | (calculation on how it works)
food    |    0      |     0.667   | (2/3)
food    |    0      |     0.667   | (2/3)
food    |    1      |     0.667   | (2/3)
Retail  |    1      |     0.25    | (1/4)
Retail  |    1      |     0.25    | (1/4)
Retail  |    1      |     0.25    | (1/4)
Retail  |    0      |     0.25    | (1/4)
```

I can get the numerator and denominator seprately but I don't know how to put them together:

**numerator:**  `df.loc[df['good_bad']==0, 'type'].value_counts().reset_index(name='counts')`

**denominator :**  `df['type'].value_counts().reset_index()`

I also try to create a function and apply to the dataframe but couldn't get to work:

```
    def industry_lost_rate(df):
        count = df.loc[loan_data['good_bad']==0, 'type'].value_counts()
        industry_sum = df['type'].value_counts()
        rate = count / industry_sum
        return pd.DataFrame({"count":count, "rate": rate})

df2 = df.groupby('type')['good_bad'].apply(industry_lost_rate(df)).reset_index()
```

Can someone tell me how to get the lost_rate? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try groupby `type` column and calculate the mean of `good_bad` column in each group with `transform`.

```py
df['lost_rate'] = 1 - df.groupby('type')['good_bad'].transform('mean').round(3)
```

```
print(df)

     type  good_bad  lost_rate
0    food         0      0.667
1    food         0      0.667
2    food         1      0.667
3  Retail         1      0.250
4  Retail         1      0.250
5  Retail         1      0.250
6  Retail         0      0.250
```